# R function to recursively merge unnamed arguments, input a list

Tags: r

I am trying to write a multi-merge alternative to `merge` which can merge-together more than two datasets on a single key.

The code I have is like this:

```
multimerge <- function(..., by, all=T) {
  value <- list(...)
  Reduce(function(x,y)merge(x,y,by=by, all=all), value)
}
```

But the thing I want to multi-merge is a list. Is it possible to pass a list argument as the `...` in a function?

For instance:

```
List <- list(
  data.frame('x'=c('a','b','c'), 'y'=1),
  data.frame('x'=c('a','b','c'), 'z'=2)
)
```

would take

`multimerge(List, by='x')`

as an argument and give:

```
x y z
a 1 2
b 1 2
c 1 2
```

as output. But I do not want to write another version of `multimerge`.

Comment: I get that output if I remove the last comma from the list object - or maybe I'm confused.

Comment: @RyanMorton thanks for pointing that out. `,` is gone. My function synax is slightly different. Turns out my example wasn't minimally reproducible. Now it is. I try to "catch" the `...` in a list, then apply it as an argument to `Reduce`. I see that now when I return `value`, it is a list of length 1 with two list elements... so `multimerge` just collapses the list back to its original form. Stupid me

Comment: I ran your code, but with a third `data.frame` added to `List` and it worked for me.

Comment: @AdamO, if it goes in as a list, why "catch" it as a list also? That just makes a list of lists, which also works to combine the inputs - just in a different way.

Comment: @RyanMorton yes precisely. Once I boiled it down, it was very clear what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is that when you pass a list into `multimerge` the list gets put into another list, which then gets collapsed back into the original list. You could just do a check for superfluous length 1 lists, and strip off that level of lists:

```
multimerge <- function(..., by, all=T) {
    value <- list(...)
    if (length(value) == 1) value <- value[[1]]
    Reduce(function(x,y)merge(x,y,by=by, all=all), value)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`purrr` has a powerful function called `flatten` that would be perfect for this problem:

```
library(purrr)

multimerge <- function(..., by, all=T) {
  value = flatten(list(...))
  Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by=by, all=T), value)
}
```

No matter what is being fed into `...`, `flatten` turns `list(...)` into a list of dataframes for `Reduce`. With this functionality, you can feed either a list of dataframes, several individual dataframes, both, or even several lists of dataframes.

You can also imitate the behavior of `flatten` by doing something like this in Base R:

```
multimerge <- function(..., by, all=T) {
  value = list(...)
  df_index = which(sapply(value, inherits, "data.frame"))
  list_index = which(sapply(value, inherits, "list"))
  value = c(value[df_index], unlist(value[list_index], recursive = FALSE))

  Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by=by, all=T), value)
}
```

This applies `unlist` only to elements that are "lists" and keep dataframes untouched. Note that I used `inherits` instead of `is.list`, because dataframes are technically also lists!

**Result:**

```
> multimerge(List, by='x')
  x y z
1 a 1 2
2 b 1 2
3 c 1 2

> multimerge(List[[1]], List[[2]], by='x')
  x y z
1 a 1 2
2 b 1 2
3 c 1 2

> multimerge(List, List[[1]], List[[2]], by='x')
  x y.x z.x y.y z.y
1 a   1   2   1   2
2 b   1   2   1   2
3 c   1   2   1   2

> multimerge(List, List, by='x')
  x y.x z.x y.y z.y
1 a   1   2   1   2
2 b   1   2   1   2
3 c   1   2   1   2
```

**Additional Notes:**

From the documentation of `?flatten`:

> These functions remove a level hierarchy from a list. They are similar to unlist(), only ever remove a single layer of hierarchy, and are **type-stable** so you always know what the type of the output is.

The key word is "type-stability", meaning it always returns the same type of data structure.

```
> flatten(list(List, List[[1]], List[[2]]))
[[1]]
  x y
1 a 1
2 b 1
3 c 1

[[2]]
  x z
1 a 2
2 b 2
3 c 2

[[3]]
  x y
1 a 1
2 b 1
3 c 1

[[4]]
  x z
1 a 2
2 b 2
3 c 2

> unlist(list(List, List[[1]], List[[2]]), recursive = FALSE)
[[1]]
  x y
1 a 1
2 b 1
3 c 1

[[2]]
  x z
1 a 2
2 b 2
3 c 2

$x
[1] a b c
Levels: a b c

$y
[1] 1 1 1

$x
[1] a b c
Levels: a b c

$z
[1] 2 2 2
```

The main difference between `flatten` and `unlist` + `recursive = FALSE` is that `flatten` "unlists" only if the output matches the data structure of the rest, where as `unlist` + `recursive = FALSE` *always* flattens one level, so in my Base R example, I needed an extra step to check whether the element is a list or a dataframe.